# NSDictionary method to java

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

i would like to do this same thing in java but i am not so sure how to do it.
I was reading that the equivalent should be a Map, but how to implement it is my problem.

I am porting an IOs app to android and i need to use this same thing in my app.

```
-(NSDictionary*) states {
NSString* state = @"SOME_STATE";
switch (self.state) {
    case 1:
        state = @"STATE1";
        break;
    case 2:
        state = @"STATE2";
        break;
    case 3:
        state = @"STATE3";
        break;
    case 4:
        state = @"STATE4";
        break;
    case 5:
        state = @"STATE5";
        break;
    case 6:
        state = @"STATE6";
        break;
    case -1:
        state = @"STATE-1";
        break;
}
return @{@"state": state};
}
```

self.state is a integer.

I will appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are lokking for:

```
public Map<String,String> states(){
        String state = @"SOME_STATE";
        switch (this.state) {
            case 1:
                state = "STATE1";
                break;
            case 2:
                state = "STATE2";
                break;
            case 3:
                state = "STATE3";
                break;
            case 4:
                state = "STATE4";
                break;
            case 5:
                state = "STATE5";
                break;
            case 6:
                state = "STATE6";
                break;
            case -1:
                state = "STATE-1";
                break;
        }
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("state", state);
        return map;
```

}

Comment: @jens just curious: can we simply do: `HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();` and not `Map<String,String> map..`? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig You can also do `HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();`

Comment: Is it because Map the most abstract interface, so that if someone later wants to change map to some other interface, it would be possible because of the use of Map, instead of HashMap?

Comment: @Unheilig If you use the `Map` Interface you can change your own implementation to an other `Map` implementation without chnage code outsite your function.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple solution. basically it shows a very simple mechanism to add stuff to your map and retrieve data (if key to data was not found then return the first data)

```
Map<Integer,String> map= new HashMap<Integer,String>();
//adding data to your map 

for(int i=1;i<=7;i++){
  map.put(i,"state"+1);
}

//retriving data
int stateNum=1;
if(map.containsKey(stateNum)){
System.out.println(map.get(stateNum);
}else{
   //get the first element in the list assuming that's what you want
   for(Entry<Integer,String> entry : map.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(entry.getValue();
    break;
}
```